# Is it possible to use 1 wifi access point to locate android mobile or would i need 3 to triangulate?

Tags: geolocation, location, position

I'm working on a project but i want to try if i can locate my position using 1 wifi access point because i only have 1 at home, or would i need to go somewhere where there are atleast 3?

Comment: Its to be used on an android phone. Ive created a map of a single room just to test it. I have 1 access point in that room, will it show on the map if i move further away from the access point

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how accurate you need the reading to be. A typical wi-fi point will have a range of something like 30m indoors or 90m outdoors.

So, if you can actually *locate* the wi-fi point perfectly and you don't need better than 90m resolution (although, technically, that's probably an up-to-180m error), one should be fine.

If you need more resolution, the more points you can get (assuming of course the points aren't sitting on top of one another in a rack or something) should allow you to refine your position.

Answer (score 0):

It is like xyz coordinate system. With one Wifi AP you will know the distance from the AP but not the direction. With two wifi APs you will know the location within a 2d plane (only the positive plane). You will need a third wifi AP for the 3rd dimension.